# Firebug Error:ReferenceError: debug is not defined

Tags: javascript, firebug

I want break in a javascript function. So on firebug console I've given:

```
debug(anchor_submit_form);
```

It's giving single line error:

> ReferenceError: debug is not defined

How do I set the breakpoint in a function?

Answer (score 1):

The firebug console is only defined when firebug is running.  So, I would do this:

```
console.log(anchor_submit_form);
```

Then launch firebug and watch the console output.  You can put a break point in the script using the firebug UI.